# Isogenies between curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

Is it always possible to find an isogeny from a hyperelliptic curve of genus 4, to a 'normal' elliptic curve (genus 1), or a product of elliptic curves?

Are such isogenies easy to compute?

Comment: What is an isogeny from a hyperelliptic curve?

Comment: @Alex B.: it's an isomorphism from its jacobian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "no". The Jacobian of a genus 4 curve is an abelian variety of dimension 4, so it cannot be isogenous to an abelian variety of dimension 1. However, it may happen, that it is isogenous to a product of 4 elliptic curves. This should be regarded as the exception, rather than the generic case.

For example, let us consider the simpler case of a genus 2 hyperelliptic curve $C$. As the answers in this [related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35060/when-is-a-product-of-elliptic-curves-isogenous-to-the-jacobian-of-a-hyperelliptic) explain, there is a degree $N^2$ isogeny from the Jacobian of such a curve to the product of two elliptic curves if and only if there is a degree $N$ map from $C$ to an elliptic curve. This is a pretty severe restriction. For example for $N=2$, this is equivalent to $C$ having a model of the form $y^2 = f(x^2)$ where $f$ is a cubic. On the other hand, an arbitrary hyperelliptic curve of genus 2 is given by $y^2=g(x)$, where $g$ is any degree 6 polynomial (in both cases no repeated roots and non-zero at 0). Most hyperelliptic curves won't admit any non-trivial morphism to an elliptic curve at all.

In [this paper](https://msp.org/obs/2013/1-1/p24.xhtml) ([backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810092931/http://www.csc.villanova.edu/%7Ejpaulhus/paulhus0108.pdf.gz)), examples are given for Jacobians of higher genus curves that are isogenous to products of elliptic curves.

I don't know much about the computational aspect of finding such an isogeny when it exists, so maybe somebody else will address that.